# Reversible, named URLs for Django flatpages (or multilingual-ng)?

Tags: django, multilingual, django-flatpages

Is there a way to have reversible, named URLs for Django flatpages (or multilingual-ng, which is flatpages + translations)?

If not, is there a similar app available which can have named URLs for pages which are editable through the admin? (And I'd rather avoid any behemoth CMSs, please.)

edit: Please see the comments in the answers below for more discussion and clarification of the question.

Comment: What do you mean by "Reversible" - can you give examples?

Comment: So that I can give a name to the page's URL, which will work with reverse() and {% url my-flatpages-url-name %}. Preferably for multilingual-ng!

Answer (score 9):

As the very last thing in your root URLConf, put

```
(r'^(?P<url>.*)$', 'django.contrib.flatpages.views.flatpage'),
```

Now you can use the `{% url %}` tag, with the view name `flatpage` and the keyword argument `url`. You can also use the `reverse()` function in views.

Comment: Great stuff, only one remark - shouldn't *flatpage* be preceded by *django.contrib.flatpages.views*, like in *django/contrib/flatpages/urls.py* ?

Comment: Thanks for answering - I think I didn't ask my question clearly enough though, since this does sort of satisfy what I asked in a clever, clean way (although I don't think you can call these "named URLs"), but doesn't help the situation I was trying to avoid: hard-coding URLs in my templates.

Comment: A flatpage only has two unique attributes: one is its database ID, the other is its URL. So those are the only things you've got to go on for uniquely identifying a flatpage, and generally the URL's a lot more memorable (and shouldn't be changing over time).

Comment: There's no benefit to using the URL as a keyword to lookup the URL itself though. I'm not adverse to adding another field to the FlatPage model for a URL name, if I could figure out how to hook it into the patterns that reverse() references.

Comment: If there's a risk someone will change the URL of your flatpages, there's a risk they'll change whatever "safe" field you go with instead. Which means you don't have a technical problem; you have a process/people problem. Fix that, then do what I suggested.

Answer (score 5):

*{% url %}* template tag works with URLconf, whereas flatpages are [handling nonexistent urls](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/tags/releases/1.2.3/django/contrib/flatpages/middleware.py).

If you really want to reverse flatpages into URLs, my guess is that you have to write your own {% flatpage_url  %} tag, which would looks like this:

```
    @register.simple_tag
    def flatpage_url(self, name):
        return FlatPage.objects.get({param}=name).url
```

-- where *{param}* is one of [FlatPage model fields](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/tags/releases/1.2.3/django/contrib/flatpages/models.py).

Also, you can merge *{% url %}* and *{% flatpageurl %}* tags together, so that the latter fallbacks to [reverse()](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/http/urls/#reverse) in case FlatPage is not found (and reverse() is what [*{% url %}* uses](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/tags/releases/1.2.3/django/template/defaulttags.py#L354)).

### EDIT:

I don't accept any more upvotes as James Bennet's answer is The One for this question (and I'm ashamed I overlooked such trivial solution) - so please upvote it.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately there's no good field in the FlatPage model to use for this, so I'll probably just add a `name` field. Maybe I can override the {% url %} tag somehow with a proxy templatetag that checks flatpage names for matches before handing it off to the django internal url templatetag.

Answer (score 1):

Aren't the proposed solutions basically the same as hardcoding the URL in the template? What's the difference between hardcoding the URL in href="URL" vs. doing it in {% url URL %}?

I think a better solution is found on: [How can I get the reverse url for a Django Flatpages template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144691/how-can-i-get-the-reverse-url-for-a-django-flatpages-template), proposed by bufh.

I think the optimal way of achieving this would be adding an extra 'name' field on the FlatPage model.

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad you understood what I now realize was an imprecisely defined question. The end-goal wasn't to be able to use `{% url %}` for flatpages, but to avoid hard-coding their URLs in my templates. The other 2 answers are well-intended and solve another interpretation of my question, but I think yours helps the most.

Comment: bufh's solution is a good start, but it still makes you write the URL for a flatpage in two places, and it makes you edit urls.py instead of being able to do it all through the admin.