# NoReverseMatch, why django doesn't find the url?

Tags: python, django

I've a little problem with my urls and I searched for some times but didnt found a correct answer.

I get the following error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /base/teams/
Reverse for 'base-home' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Here is my urls:

- from the project:

  ```
  from django.conf.urls import url, patterns, include
  from django.contrib import admin

  urlpatterns = patterns('',
  # Examples:

  url(r'^base/$', include('django.contrib.flatpages.urls'), name='base-home'),
  url(r'^base/contact/$', include('django.contrib.flatpages.urls'), name='base-contact'),
  url(r'^base/teams/', include('app.urls'), name='base-teams'),

  # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
  # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

  # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
  url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
  )
  ```
- from the app:

  ```
  from django.conf.urls import *
  urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'app.views.teams_list', name='teams'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w\d]+)/$', 'app.views.teams_list', name='teams_slug'),
    url(r'^show/(?P<id>\d+)/$', 'app.views.show_personne', name='show_personne'),
  )
  ```

Here is the call in the template:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'base-home' %}">Website</a>
```

This error is raised when is try to load the page 'base/teams/'. I don't understand why he doesn't match the base-home view name ...

Thanks for your help,
dg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be because this line

```
url(r'^base/$', include('django.contrib.flatpages.urls'), name='base-home'),
```

doesn't actually resolve to a view. Instead it is an `include` statement.

See [How can I get the reverse url for a Django Flatpages template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144691/how-can-i-get-the-reverse-url-for-a-django-flatpages-template)